# What should we do with off-topic tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

We've got a bunch of tags that are off-topic for this site.

- [seinfeld](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seinfeld) (6 questions, all from one user) I don't think this has anything to do with English. You could say a question that came from someone's confusion with the show is on-topic (and you're right) but do we need a tag for this? Also, only one user has tagged any question with "Seinfeld". Should we add a [the-simpsons](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-simpsons) tag also?
- [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) (11 questions) Isn't this site about English?
- [cooking](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) (2 questions) is "English words about cooking" useful enough to warrant its own tag? So far, there are only two questions tagged with "cooking", I don't think it will be missed.
- [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) (19 questions) Haha, isn't this one a little bit self-contradictory? Kind of like "This page is intentionally left blank"?

What should we do with these tags?

Answer (score 3):

For the six questions tagged [meaning-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) [seinfeld](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seinfeld), the posts can be edited to remove the [seinfeld](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seinfeld) tag.  You can indicate your agreement by voting on this post.

Answer (score 2):

Of the 19 [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions, I have edited 14 of them to provide tags.

The remaining 5 are closed and have nonpositive scores.  I expect that they will eventually be deleted automatically anyway, so I haven't bothered.

Answer (score 1):

Single-use tags are, in general, not a problem.  If, after a half a year, the tag still hasn't been used a second time, it will be [automatically removed](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418) unless it [has a tag wiki](//meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1158).

[untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a special tag automatically added to questions that are migrated from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the [cooking](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) tag from questions [10169](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/10169/5289) and [15147](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/15147/5289) due to their narrow applicability.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tags don't fit with the others. They are asking about whether there is existing English phrases for concepts that they are familiar with in another language. That is a specific type of question about the English language. (ELU has a [translation tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) for this type of question.)

Whether we want a tag for that specific type of question (and if so, whether we want specific instances of the tag for every language) I think this is a bigger question and merits a separate discussion, so I've [posted it as a new question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/do-we-need-translation-from-other-languages-tags).