# Do we need translation from other languages tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's [recently been pointed out](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/lets-clean-up-tags?cb=1) that we have a [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tag.

I guess there are two questions here:

- Do we want a tag for "finding the right translation in English for a very specific idiom/phrase in another language"? ELU has a bunch of these questions but I'm not sure how many we have here, or if a "translation" tag encourages proofreading/dictionary requests.
- If we do want to tag those questions, do we want/need specific [french-translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-translation), [italian-translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-translation), [japanese-translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-translation), etc., tags?

Possibly relevant: ELU has a [translation tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) for this type of question. We [also have a translation tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), but it seems to be used a bit more inconsistently, and not always as described above.

Comment: I think using a generic "translation" tag seems like the simplest solution. What does everyone else think?

Comment: @Wendi - Part of me agrees with you – it's easier to have one tag than several. Then again, what are tags used for? What if we have regular users who are fluent in French, or fluent in Italian, and those users want to find all the French (or Italian) translation questions, to lend their expertise. If they are all tagged with `translation`, then those questions get lumped together with all the German, Japanese, and Arabic translation queries. It might be best to keep the language-specific tags, so that curious onlookers can easily find all the questions related to one particular language.

Comment: @J.R. I can see the argument for that, and I'm not necessarily disagreeing. But on the other hand, what if we have users who are skilled at taking a concept familiar to another language and looking for the perfect English phrase for it? Those users wouldn't be able to find all the translation questions if there's a separate tag for every separate language. The questions do have to explain the concept in English anyway to be on topic, so it seems to me that being able to find the phrase for a foreign concept is possibly a more relevant skill than knowing the original language?

Comment: Then again, this is English language **learners**. It's possible the explanation won't be that great and knowing the original language is more helpful here than on ELU (though if knowing the original language becomes *necessary*, I think the question becomes off-topic). Now I'm starting to wonder if there's a case for using both sets of tags (`translation` and `french-translation`)...

Comment: @starsplusplus - Every question can have up to five tags. [Most of these](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french), for example, are tagged with both the `french` tag and the `translation` tag. I think we should keep a `french` tag, but, with that and the more general `translation` tag, I don't see a need for a `french-translation` tag.

Comment: @J.R. I think it's always a good idea to have tags be more descriptive if possible. What would the tag wiki say for `french`? Is it intended to only be used for French translation? If so, `french-translation` would make it clearer what the tag was meant to be used for. If you make tags too vague, people can come in and use them inconsistently. On the other hand, if you make them too narrow, you can accidentally exclude questions from sensibly using the tag - which brings me back to the question of whether it makes sense for the scope of the `french` tag to cover anything outside translation.

Comment: As I envision it, the `french` tag could be used for French translation questions, or English expressions derived  from French, etc. I don't think there are so many of these that we need to have a `French-translation` tag and a `French-expressions` tag, etc.

Comment: @J.R. That's a reasonable point. Just to be clear, do you mean loanwords/loan phrases (*faux pas*, *café*, etc.) when you say English expressions derived from French? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @J.R. I think that makes a lot of sense. I didn't see the need for both `translation` and `French-translation`, but keeping just `French` around is a sound idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a summary from my previous comments, but I'm ready to formulate an answer now.

My recommendation is to use multiple tags, rather than combining them into a dual purpose tag.

Consider questions about the following:

- *C'est la vie*
- *hors d' oeuvres*
- *Je me lance, vers la gloire*
- *Hasta Mañana*
- *pronto vs. ASAP*
- *Feliz Navidad, prospero ano y felicidad*

Conceivably, this could lead to six different tags (one for each of these):

- [french-expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-expressions)
- [french-loanwords](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-loanwords)
- [french-translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-translation)
- [spanish-expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-expressions)
- [spanish-loanwords](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-loanwords)
- [spanish-translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-translation)

I think it would be better to keep this down to four tags, and put two tags on each question:

- [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) [expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions)
- [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) [loanwords](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords)
- [french](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) [translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)
- [spanish](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish) [expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions)
- [spanish](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish) [loanwords](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords)
- [spanish](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish) [translation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)

The difference between four and six may seem trivial, but the savings become more significant with more languages. If we were to repeat this process for German, Arabic, Italian, and Japanese, and do this with other tags such as [phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) and [slang](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang), things would really get out of hand.

Bottom line: I think it's better to have N+M tags, and combine them as needed, instead of NxM tags, and account for every possible combination.

Comment: You make a good case. Seems logical. One question - at the moment, [very few of the questions tagged "translation"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) have a secondary tag for language. Do you think it's worth going through and adding `french`, `japanese`, whatever tags to those questions?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, particularly if the tags already exist.

Comment: I added the [tag:japanese] tag to one question, but I couldn't really find any others where it was applicable.

Comment: And pazzo immediately removed the tag, so I guess not everyone agrees we should have tags like these! :-)

Comment: @snail - Fixed.

Comment: I think we should come up with a tag wiki to describe what sorts of questions concerning translation are on-topic.  After all, the focus is on English on this site―we don't want people to see the tags and post translation requests with no effort put in.

Comment: Maybe we could have a [tag:hindi] tag too: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29758/230